# Redmine: Filter headings in Table Of Contents

Tags: redmine

In Redmine `{{toc}}` creates a Table of Contents of the Wiki page. By default it shows all headings on that page (in my case: h1,h2,h3,h4). I only want to show the most important headings h1 & h2. Is there a parameter for the `{{toc}}` command to filter out certain headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{toc}}` macro is currently not configurable and further (apart from setting it to left-align or right-align).

It will always show all headings up to and including level 4.